# WPF Datagrid from large CSV file in C#

Tags: c#, wpf, csv

I'm trying to import a CSV into a `List<Model>()`.

My CSV has more than 30,000 lines/rows of data. I'm finding it takes a very long time to load this into a model list that is then bound to a `datagrid`.

I've tried using `CsvHelper` and just `File.ReadAllLines(file).ToList();`, both take a very long time to load.

Any suggestions on speeding up the import of the CSV data?

I'm guessing that it's perhaps not the reading of the file that is taking so long. Could it be that I'm storing each line as a class ? I'm guessing that is all stored in memory, all 30,000 entries. Is there a better way of doing this to fill a DataGrid?

Code:

```
        // PersonDataView
    <DataGrid X:Name="Employees" > 

    </DataGrid>

    public class PersonModel
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// The unique identifier for the person.
        /// </summary>
        public int Id { get; set; }

        public string FirstName { get; set; }

        public string LastName { get; set; }

        public string EmailAddress { get; set; }

        public string CellphoneNumber { get; set; }

        public string Other { get; set; }
    }

    public class PersonDataViewModel : Screen
    {

      public List<PersonModel> _employees = new List<PersonModel>();
      public List<PersonModel> Employees
      {
        get { return _employees; }
        set { 
          _employees = value;
          NotifyOfPropertyChange(() => EmployeeData)
        }
      }

      public PersonDataViewModel()
      {
        Employees = new BindableCollection<PersonModel>(GetPersonData_All());
      }
    }


    public static BindableCollection<PrizeModel>     GetPersonData_All(this List<string> lines)
    {
        List<PrizeModel> output = new List<PrizeModel>();
        string file = "EmployeeModel.csv";

        var lines = File.ReadAllLines(filepath);

        foreach (string line in lines)
        {
            string[] cols = line.Split(',');

            PersonModel p = new PersonModel();
            p.Id = int.Parse(cols[0]);
            p.FirstName = int.Parse(cols[1]);
            p.LastName = cols[2];
            p.EmailAddress = decimal.Parse(cols[3]);
            p.CellphoneNumber = double.Parse(cols[4]);
            p.Other = double.Parse(cols[4]);

            output.Add(p);
        }

        return output;
    }
```

Comment: Can you try this and see if your performance improves https://medium.com/@nuno.caneco/c-file-readlines-vs-file-readalllines-4742d738064e

Comment: @G-Man Still taking quite a long time, I have it running right now and it's at 5 minutes and still going.

Comment: File.ReadLines(fileName).ToList(); should be slightly better than ReadAllLines

Comment: [This guy](https://dfederm.com/learn-span-by-implementing-a-high-performance-csv-parser/) implemented a CSV parser using Span<T> and achieved some order of magnitude improvements.

Comment: You can also refer Dans answer using LoadBound()
https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/20145/faster-way-of-reading-csv-to-grid/20147

Comment: I'm guessing that it's perhaps not the reading of the file that is taking so long. Could it be that I'm storing each line as a class `<Model>`? I'm guessing that is all stored in memory, all 30,000 entries. Is there a better way of doing this to fill a DataGrid?

Comment: Can you show us the actual code? We need to see the actual code that parses this text into classes.  Also for the perfomance of the grid you should use virtualization. So that you only render the rows that are visible on the screen and not the entire set of data.  Sometime you need to set ScrollViewer.CanContentScroll to true on the datagrid object itself to make virtualization work.  Try setting explicit column widths this could shave off a few seconds from the rendering of the rows as well.

Comment: @Darkonekt I Didn't have my code with me, but I've quickly typed out basically what I was doing. I've updated my question.

Comment: Is the user really going to scroll through 30,000 rows? Have you considered loading the file into a local database and letting the user filter from there? Bcp should load 30,000 rows into a sql express table way quicker than 5 minutes. Alternatively, read the first 100 lines and transform in a task on a background thread. Return to the ui thread, add to an observablecollection bound to itemssource. Await task delay 100ms and repeat until end of file. The ui should be responsive. The datagrid slider will grow so the user can see stuff is happening.

Comment: @Andy I'll try that out. I'm not familiar with async await tasks, but this is a good enough place to start as any. Any suggestions on learning materials/tutorials?

Comment: For performance problems it is always a good idea to run a profiler. I would not be surprised if your program spends most of its time in the UI and not in the reading and parsing. You can also try to load your data without displaying it anywhere to see how long that takes.

Answer (score 0):

i dunno if you have always problem, but i share my experience about that. Its difficult to win time at reading file, except maybe if you cut file in more parts and use multithread to read the different parts.

Where you could win lot of time is to read and process instead of i read all file then i process, i read one line and i process one line..

to help to do that you could use the technick "[Blocking Collection](https://learn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/dotnet/api/system.collections.concurrent.blockingcollection-1.getconsumingenumerable?view=netcore-3.1)"
example

if you could cut your file in multipart, its better

```
void ReadAndProcessFiles(string[] filePaths)
{
    // Our thread-safe collection used for the handover.
    var lines = new BlockingCollection<string>();

    // Build the pipeline.
    var phase1 = Task.Run(() =>
    {
        try
        {
            foreach (var filePath in filePaths)
            {
                using (var reader = new StreamReader(filePath))
                {
                    string line;

                    while ((line = reader.ReadLine()) != null)
                    {
                        // Hand over to phase 2 and continue reading.
                        lines.Add(line);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        finally
        {
            lines.CompleteAdding();
        }
    });

    var phase2 = Task.Run(() =>
    {
        // Process lines on a ThreadPool thread
        // as soon as they become available.
        foreach (var line in lines.GetConsumingEnumerable())
        {
            //DO something during phase2
        }
    });

    // Block until both tasks have completed.
    // This makes this method prone to deadlocking.
    // Consider using 'await Task.WhenAll' instead.
    Task.WaitAll(phase1, phase2);
}
```

IF you could chain more phases that will be better and better